# Abort intermediary futures when processing elements in futures::stream::Stream concurrently

Tags: asynchronous, rust, future

I am trying to "connect" to multiple peers and "process" them concurrently. For single processes (named "tasks") this works fine. However, with multiple tasks I want to consume the process once a peer has processed it. In the following setup I have 3 tasks where I want the second task to abort for all other peers once a peer completes it. This should include any future peers also from the `create_new_conn_fut` future.

```rust
use futures::stream::StreamExt;
use rand::Rng;

pub async fn process(peer: &str, duration: core::time::Duration, task_id: &str) {
    // simulate processing by sleeping
    tokio::time::sleep(duration).await;
    println!("task #{} done for {}", task_id, peer);
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let peers = vec!["peer A", "peer B", "peer C"];
    let peers = futures::stream::iter(peers);

    let (tx, rx) = tokio::sync::mpsc::channel(100);

    let rx = tokio_stream::wrappers::ReceiverStream::new(rx);
    let rx = peers.chain(rx);
    
    let handle_conn_fut = rx.for_each_concurrent(0,
        |peer| async move {
            let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

            println!("connecting to {}", peer);
            process(peer, core::time::Duration::from_secs(1), "1").await;

            process(peer, core::time::Duration::from_secs(rng.gen_range(5..15)), "2").await;

            process(peer, core::time::Duration::from_secs(1), "3").await;
        }
    );
    
    let create_new_conn_fut = async move {
        for peer in ["peer D", "peer E"] {
            tx.send(peer).await.unwrap();
        }
    };

    // awaits all futures in parallell
    futures::future::join(handle_conn_fut, create_new_conn_fut).await;
}
```

output:

```
connecting to peer A
connecting to peer B
connecting to peer C
connecting to peer D
connecting to peer E
task #1 done for peer A
task #1 done for peer B
task #1 done for peer C
task #1 done for peer D
task #1 done for peer E
task #2 done for peer C
task #3 done for peer C
task #2 done for peer D
task #2 done for peer A
task #2 done for peer B
task #3 done for peer D
task #3 done for peer A
task #3 done for peer B
task #2 done for peer E
task #3 done for peer E
```

I would rather task #2 was aborted for all peers once a peer has completed it and redirect all future peers to only do task #1 and task #3.

Illustrating this I have the following

```
     A                B           ....          E
     ↓                ↓                         ↓
async task #1    async task #1             async task #1
     ↓                ↓                         ↓
async task #2    async task #2             async task #2
     ↓                ↓                         ↓
async task #3    async task #3             async task #3
     ↓                ↓                         ↓
    done             done                      done
```

and I want to short-circuit `async task #1` once any peer (A-E) has completed it. So given that ex. B completed it first it would look like this:

```
     A                B           ....          E          ....           F (future peer)
     ↓                ↓                         ↓                         ↓
async task #1    async task #1             async task #1             async task #1 
     ↓                ↓                         ↓                         ↓
     ↓           async task #2                  ↓                         ↓
     ↓                ↓                         ↓                         ↓
async task #3    async task #3             async task #3             async task #3
     ↓                ↓                         ↓                         ↓
    done             done                      done                      done
```

So my desired output would be:

```
connecting to peer A
connecting to peer B
connecting to peer C
connecting to peer D
connecting to peer E
task #1 done for peer A
task #1 done for peer B
task #1 done for peer C
task #1 done for peer D
task #1 done for peer E
task #2 done for peer C    <- will abort all other task #2
task #3 done for peer A
task #3 done for peer B
task #3 done for peer C
task #3 done for peer D
task #3 done for peer E
```

I have looked into [`futures::future::AbortHandle`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/struct.AbortHandle.html), but I think this is only for single futures - Since the  `futures::stream::AbortRegistration` does not have the Clone trait?

How would one implement something like this?

Answer (score 0):

An idea would be to use `tokio::select` with branches for checking if either the task is done or if it has been cancelled:

```rust
use futures::stream::StreamExt;
use rand::Rng;
use futures::future;

pub async fn process(peer: &str, duration: core::time::Duration, task_id: &str) {
    // simulate processing by sleeping
    tokio::time::sleep(duration).await;
    println!("task #{} done for {}", task_id, peer);
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let peers = vec!["peer A", "peer B", "peer C"];
    let peers = futures::stream::iter(peers);

    let (tx, rx) = tokio::sync::mpsc::channel(100);

    let rx = tokio_stream::wrappers::ReceiverStream::new(rx);
    let rx = peers.chain(rx);

    let notify = std::sync::Arc::new(tokio::sync::Notify::new());
    let done_with_task_2 = std::rc::Rc::new(std::cell::RefCell::new(false));
    
    let handle_conn_fut = rx.for_each_concurrent(0, |peer| {
        let notify = notify.clone();
        let done_with_task_2 = done_with_task_2.clone();

        async move {
            let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

            println!("connecting to {}", peer);
            process(peer, core::time::Duration::from_secs(1), "1").await;

            // task #2
            tokio::select! {
                done = async { 
                    if *done_with_task_2.borrow() {
                        future::ready(()).await
                    } else {
                        future::pending().await
                    }
                } => {}
                process = process(peer, core::time::Duration::from_secs(rng.gen_range(5..10)), "2") => {
                    notify.notify_waiters();
                    done_with_task_2.replace(true);
                }
                cancel = notify.notified() => {}
            }

            process(peer, core::time::Duration::from_secs(1), "3").await;

            process(peer, core::time::Duration::from_secs(20), "4").await;
        }
    }
    );
    
    let create_new_conn_fut = async move {
        for peer in ["peer D", "peer E"] {
            tx.send(peer).await.unwrap();
        }
        // a new peer after 15 seconds
        tokio::time::sleep(core::time::Duration::from_secs(15)).await;
        tx.send("peer F").await.unwrap()
    };

    // awaits all futures in parallell
    futures::future::join(handle_conn_fut, create_new_conn_fut).await;
}
```

output:

```
connecting to peer A
connecting to peer B
connecting to peer C
connecting to peer D
connecting to peer E
task #1 done for peer A
task #1 done for peer B
task #1 done for peer C
task #1 done for peer D
task #1 done for peer E
task #2 done for peer B
task #3 done for peer B
task #3 done for peer E
task #3 done for peer D
task #3 done for peer C
task #3 done for peer A
connecting to peer F
task #1 done for peer F
task #3 done for peer F
task #4 done for peer B
task #4 done for peer E
task #4 done for peer D
task #4 done for peer C
task #4 done for peer A
task #4 done for peer F
```

However, the code becomes slightly verbose. Is there a better way to write this?

One could probably use [`futures::future::Either`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/enum.Either.html#impl-Future) or use a [`shared`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/trait.FutureExt.html#method.shared) future.